# Preventing accidental alteration of a javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have run into some trouble with finding a way to prevent accidental alterations of an object's prototype. The example below should help clarify my issue:

```
var Enemy, enemy1, enemy2;

Enemy = (function() {
  function Enemy() {}

  Enemy.prototype.speed = 10;

  Enemy.prototype.stats = {
    strength: 15
    dexterity: 12
  };

  return Enemy;

})();

enemy1 = new Enemy();
enemy2 = new Enemy();

enemy1.speed = 20;
enemy1.stats.strength = 25;

console.log("enemy1 speed: " + enemy1.speed);
console.log("enemy2 speed: " + enemy2.speed);
console.log("enemy1 str: " + enemy1.stats.strength);
console.log("enemy2 str: " + enemy2.stats.strength);
```

Result:

```
console: enemy1 speed: 20
console: enemy2 speed: 10
console: enemy1 str: 25
console: enemy2 str: 25
```

As you can see, editing a primitive property on enemy1 (e.g. `speed`) does not affect enemy2. But when a property within an object property is changed on enemy1 (e.g. `stats.strength`), this seems to actually be altering the prototype instead of the instance.

I believe this is because neither enemy1 nor enemy2 have a local property called `stats`, so `enemy1.stats` resolves to the prototype value, meaning that its value for `strength` is altered.

I have come up with a way to solve this, by changing Enemy's constructor to:

```
function Enemy() {
    //using jQuery to deep copy the stats property in the prototype
    this.stats = $.extend(this, Enemy.prototype.stats); 
}
```

This initializes a local property of stats, which means a reference to `enemy1.stats` no longer references the prototype.

But I'm not entirely happy with this approach as I need to remember to do this for each object property, when I add more. Not only that, but I've also now got fatter Enemy objects as they each need to store a copy of the stats object.

Is there a better approach I can use here?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want `speed` and `stats` to be *instance* specific properties, so you should initialize those values in the constructor function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this seems to actually be altering the prototype instead of the instance.

No, it's altering the object that the prototype refers to. But it comes to much the same thing. :-)

> I believe this is because neither enemy1 nor enemy2 have a local property called stats, so enemy1.stats resolves to the prototype value, meaning that its value for strength is altered.

Exactly, yes. (The terminology is "own" property, rather than "local" property, but you've got it exactly right.)

> Is there a better approach I can use here?

I think what you have is a good approach. If you wanted, you could automate it (looping through the properties on `this` and, for any that have `typeof` as `"object"`, running them through `extend`), but fundamentally if you're going to be modifying the properties of objects associated with the instance, those objects need to be on the instance, not the prototype.

FWIW, I probably wouldn't have `stats` on the prototype at all, just in the constructor.